# Render Rmd file with pipe formatting for tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

**Problem**

I have a `.Rmd` template file which I currently use to render PDFs using `rmarkdown::render`.

I need the option to also render the `.Rmd` as a markdown file. I have tried setting `output_format` to `md_document` in `rmarkdown::render` however this produces a markdown file containing lots of html tags for the tables etc. I don't want any html; I need it to be readable in a console, with tables formatted using the markdown pipe styling.

**What I've tried**

I tried setting `output_format` to

```
output_format(knitr = rmarkdown::knitr_options(opts_knit = list(knitr.table.format = "pipe")), 
pandoc = rmarkdown::pandoc_options(to = rmarkdown::rmarkdown_format())
```

but this style produces a markdown file with html tags instead of piped tables.

How do I set the markdown render settings to render as I need?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, including a sample document for which this occurs.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar problem. `results='asis'` isn't working for me either

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try adding `results='asis'` to knitr opts